# Checkbox is not checked, even though I do it with code

Tags: java, checkbox, game-development

I'm writing a Java Game similar to Tetris for a school project. In the game I have a checkbox to turn music on/off.

My problem is that the checkbox, even though I set it to be checked, is NOT checked when I click it (don't understand me wrong, not AFTER, but before/at the same moment when I clicked it).

Okay so, in my code where I first initialize the checkbox I set it to be checked based on a variable provided in another class.

I tried debugging everything that is going on with the checkbox but I didn't get anything I didn't already knew.

Here's the code where I initialize the box:

```java
music_cbox = TexturesHandler.getCheckboxTemplate();
music_cbox.setName("Music");
music_cbox.addMouseListener(Retris.getButtonHandler());
music_cbox.setLocation(Retris.WIDTH / 2 - 25, 250);

 // Setting it to checked based on the variable

if(!Retris.getAudioHandler().canPlay()) {
    music_cbox.setIcon(TexturesHandler.getUncheckedCheckBoxStyle());
    music_cbox.setSelected(false);
    System.out.println("box not selected");
} else {
    music_cbox.setIcon(TexturesHandler.getCheckedCheckBoxStyle());
    music_cbox.setSelected(true);
    System.out.println("box selected");
    }
```

The canPlay variable only gets changed when you CLICK the box:

```
if(box.isSelected()) {
    Retris.getAudioHandler().canPlay(false);
    Retris.getAudioHandler().stopMusic();
    System.out.println("Music disabled");
    box.setIcon(TexturesHandler.getUncheckedCheckBoxStyle());
    break;
    // (in a switch statement)
} else {
    Retris.getAudioHandler().canPlay(true);
    Retris.getAudioHandler().startMusic("Main_Menu.wav", "Main Menu", 0.1F);
    System.out.println("Music enabled");
    box.setIcon(TexturesHandler.getCheckedCheckBoxStyle());
    break;
}
```

I also tried `box.setSelected()` after setting the new icon and all, but somehow when i first click the box, it does the `else` part instead of the `if` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps but I noted that in the initialization you call music_cbox.setSelected() but then in your if statement you call box.isSelected()

Are these the same box? Could explain why you set the variable but then check another one.

Comment: Yes they are the same boxes, just the first code is in the `OptionsFrame.class` and the other code is in the `HoverClickHandler.class`. But the boxes are the same

Comment: @DieWolfBuddies My only thought is to set up a print statement or console output, when the events are triggered.

Confirming that the button is retaining its 'set' state and not being changed before it gets to the If (confirming not a scope issue)

Comment: That's what i did. I logged everything with the console but somehow when it reaches the second code block it is NOT checked, even though console says it never got changed

Comment: @DieWolfBuddies I would attempt a print before the if statement then to confirm the state check is accurate to your console.

Against without more code its hard to address the issue, but the things to confirm would be its not a scope issue (state is retained) and that the check itself is working.

If both the 2 above are confirmed then its something between those 2 actions that is acting on the check.

It could even be your game thread not acting on proper scope.

Comment: @DieWolfBuddies were you able to fix this issue?